# Write an array into table (ListObject) - out of memory

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, memory, listobject

I have a problem with entering an array into a table which is formatted as a ListObject.
I used the following code, but this is not working for all cases.

The problematic function is embedded in the main Sub as follows.

```
Dim SFH As New SheetFilterhandler

Set SFH.SetTable = loSourceList
SFH.SaveFilters
SFH.DisableFilters
Call UpdateListObject(loSourceList, loImportList)
SFH.EnableFilters
```

And the function can be reduced to this:

```
Public Function UpdateListObject(loTarget As ListObject, loSource As ListObject) As Boolean

On Error GoTo CreateErr
Dim PreviousContent As Variant
Dim Export As Variant

Export = loSource.DataBodyRange.value
PreviousContent = loTarget.DataBodyRange.value

Dim CurrentContent As Variant
ReDim CurrentContent(UBound(PreviousContent) + UBound(Export), UBound(PreviousContent, 2))

For ExportIndex = 1 To UBound(Export)
    For PreviousContentIndex = 1 To UBound(PreviousContent)
        'Export and PreviousContent is compared and written into CurrentContent
    Next PreviousContentIndex
    'new items
    If ItemNotExisting Then
        NewContentCounter = NewContentCounter + 1
        loTarget.ListRows.Add
        For i = 1 To UBound(Export, 2)
            CurrentContent(UBound(PreviousContent) + NewContentCounter, i) = Export(ExportIndex, i)
        Next i
    End If
Next ExportIndex

loTarget.DataBodyRange.Value2 = CurrentContent 'problematic line
UpdateListObject = True
Exit Function
CreateErr:
    UpdateListObject = False
    GetErrMsg = Err.Description
    Debug.Print "UpdateListObject: " & GetErrMsg
    Debug.Print PreviousContentIndex & "," & ExportIndex
End Function
```

**This code is working fine for:**

> CurrentContent Variant/Variant(1 to 1294, 1 to 55);
> loTarget.DataBodyRange.Value2(1 to 647, 1 to 55)

**But for the following it is not working:**

> CurrentContent Variant/Variant(1 to 3071, 1 to 20);
> loTarget.DataBodyRange.Value2(1 to 1543, 1 to 20)

The size is different, because ArrayName has only empty entries for the rows greater than `ListObject` max rows and can be ignored.

In this case I used the Debug.Print to show the error description.

```
GetErrMsg = Err.Description
Debug.Print GetErrMsg
```

The output was `Nicht genügend Speicher` which could be translated `not enough memory`.
If there is any limit, I do not understand it, because.
1294 x 55 = 71170 and 3071 x 20 = 61420

The same behavior was seen also without the table.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .ListObjects(1).Unlist
    .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Clear
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(UBound(CurrentContent) + 1, UBound(CurrentContent, 2))) = CurrentContent
End With
```

Sample data of CurrentContent

| Expression | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CurrentContent(1,1) | 3709745 | Variant/Double |
| CurrentContent(1,2) | "String 1" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,3) | #11.11.2023 11:11:11# | Variant/Date |
| CurrentContent(1,4) | #11.11.2023# | Variant/Date |
| CurrentContent(1,5) | "String 2 [1234567]" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,6) | "String 3" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,7) | "String 4" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,8) | "String 5" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,9) | "String 6" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,10) | "String 7" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,11) | "" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,12) | "XX" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,13) | "" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,14) | "" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,15) | "1234567, 1234567" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,16) | "String 8" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,17) | "String 9" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,18) | #11.11.2023 11:11:11# | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,19) | "Max Mustermann (1234567)" | Variant/String |
| CurrentContent(1,20) | Empty | Variant/Empty |

Comment: Please show us some sample data - otherwise it is pretty hard to help you.

Comment: Which sampe data do you need? Of the array? It is a huge table of mostly strings. Or do you need some more info how the table and arrays are filled in the code?

Comment: Then show us at least a small part of the data. And yes: further details regarding the code would help as well.

Comment: I added some more code and also sample data of the array.

Comment: You have `ReDim CurrentContent(UBound(PreviousContent) + UBound(Export), UBound(PreviousContent, 2))`  *before*  `PreviousContent = loTarget.DataBodyRange.value`   ?

Comment: Any event handlers on the worksheet for the target listobject?

Comment: @Tim: You are right. In the code it is the other way around. It is corrected here now.

Comment: I also added the code where the function is embedded.
There are also no event handlers (only ScreenUpdating).

Comment: If you comment out the line `On Error GoTo CreateErr` then where does it error?

Comment: loTarget.DataBodyRange.value = CurrentContent

Comment: I tried the following: I deleted all rows of the table and only left 2 rows. The command loTarget.DataBodyRange.value = CurrentContent errors, but fills the table up to row 971 (with 19 columns)

Comment: It seems to be not the problem with the table but with the array. I adapted the description.

Answer (score 0):

I have a column where all Cells have a large string. When this column is deleted there is no issue anymore.

I guess there is a limit of characters in an array which can be written into `Range`. At the moment I do not know this limit.

Answer (score 0):

I checked again the what is the root cause. I can not add a 1593 long string into a `Range` which begins with 88 times "=" (equal to character). This string in the array can not be written, even if I would do it like this:

```
Range("A1") = ProblematicString
```

But in this case the error is: "Anwendungs- oder objektdefinierter Fehler", "Application or object defined error"

This problem can be reduced to

```
Range("A1") = "=="
```